# Ember data and RestAdapter

Tags: ember.js

I'm building an ember application with a RESTAdapter to access my data in an api. I'm using the latest version of ember-data from https://github.com/emberjs/data/downloads.

This is how I'm declaring my RESTAdatpter-

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://example.com'
});
```

but I dont think it's declared correctly as the ember inspector in the browser says that it cannot detect an adapter. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Any other code available? Do you see API calls in you console going to `example.com` or another address (e.g. `localhost`)?

Comment: it's going to localhost!

Comment: Can you post any other initialization code?

Comment: Anything in particular? I dont have any other js which refer to the adapter/ server name.

Comment: I think I had the same issue at the beginning and found an answer somewhere that worked. Try reopening the adapter using `DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({ // same options as above })`

Comment: From the console errors I'm getting, it seems that the RESTAdapter is undefined?

Comment: Can you try setting up a JSbin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I changed the ember data version to 1.0.0-beta.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and was able to get it to work using the following:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
  host: 'http://example.com'
})
```

I'm not sure if the [guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/connecting-to-an-http-server/#toc_customizing-urls) need to be updated or if there's a different way to accomplish this.